# Getting Healthkit step data from a time range in an Independent watchOS App

Tags: swift, xcode, apple-watch, healthkit, watchos

Sorry if this is a simple question but I'm having trouble finding a concrete answer.
When I created an app for fitbit I needed to create a script to be run from the Fitbit app because the fitbit watch didn't hold all the historical step data I needed.

I'm wondering if this will be the case with an Apple Watch app.

I'm hoping to create an independent watchOS App that accesses the user's steps from within a data time range. The time range would ideally be able to pull from the last seven days. I also want to be able to get the steps from time ranges based on the last time the app was used. (For example, the app hasn't been used since 9:30AM two days ago, on the next load it should get all steps from then until now). Then it's not used for half an hour, so the last 30 mins of steps should be retrieved on load.

Is it possible for this type of data to be accessed from an independent watch app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The watch has the last 7 days of health data so you should be able to do what you describe.

Comment: Thank you. Could you tell me where you found this info? It's possible the source might be useful with other things I want to do in the app.

Comment: Take a look at [earliestPermittedSampleDate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkhealthstore/1614166-earliestpermittedsampledate)